# Joining a calendar table on date to a table of items returns all NULLS (adding missing dates to table by a group)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to join a table of dates to an existing table of items.  I want to add the missing dates for each item see items table:

[original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITRbq.png)

```
date    item    price
1/1/2018    toys    22.82
1/3/2018    toys    28.99
1/6/2018    toys    32.56
1/2/2018    shoes   41.23
1/4/2018    shoes   62.74
1/10/2018   shoes   35.16
```

I need to fill in missing dates for each item with a NULL price so then I can estimate it
so I want this result:
[result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5NcS.png)

```
date    item    price
1/1/2018    toys    22.82
1/2/2018    toys    NULL
1/3/2018    toys    28.99
1/4/2018    toys    NULL
1/5/2018    toys    NULL
1/6/2018    toys    32.56
1/2/2018    shoes   41.23
1/3/2018    shoes   NULL
1/4/2018    shoes   62.74
1/5/2018    shoes   NULL
1/6/2018    shoes   NULL
1/7/2018    shoes   NULL
1/8/2018    shoes   NULL
1/9/2018    shoes   NULL
1/10/2018   shoes   35.16
```

I have tried the following:

```
    select c.day, e.item, e.price
from db.days c cross join
     (select distinct item from db.items e)
     left join
     db.items e
     on c.day = e.date_added;
```

It gives me the following:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6lGS.png)

```
date    item    price
1/1/2018    NULL    NULL
1/2/2018    NULL    NULL
1/3/2018    NULL    NULL
1/4/2018    NULL    NULL
1/5/2018    NULL    NULL
1/6/2018    NULL    NULL
1/2/2018    NULL    NULL
1/3/2018    NULL    NULL
1/4/2018    NULL    NULL
1/5/2018    NULL    NULL
1/6/2018    NULL    NULL
1/7/2018    NULL    NULL
1/8/2018    NULL    NULL
1/9/2018    NULL    NULL
1/10/2018   NULL    NULL
```

How can I get rid of the NULLs and get my desired result above? I am using SQLite Studio

Comment: What is `db.days`?

Comment: a list of all calendar dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(d) as (
   select min(date) from toys
   union all
   select date(c.d, '+1 day') from cte c where c.d < (select max(date) from toys)
)
select c.d, t1.item, t4.price from cte c 
cross join (select distinct t.item from toys t) t1 
left join toys t4 on t4.date = c.d and t4.item = t1.item 
where c.d <= (select max(t3.date) from toys t3 where t3.item = t1.item) and c.d >= (select min(t3.date) from toys t3 where t3.item = t1.item)
```

Comment: Gives the top price but the rest of the prices in the dataset are null

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will work =)

```
   select c.day, e.item, 
   (select price
    from items i
    where i.date_added = c.day and i.item = e.item) price
   from days c left join (select distinct item, min(date_added) min_date, max(date_added) max_date from items group by item) e
   where (c.day BETWEEN  min_date and max_date)
   order by item, day
```

Scripts:

```
create table days (day date);

INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-01-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-02-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-03-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-04-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-05-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-06-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-07-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-08-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-09-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-10-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-11-06');
INSERT INTO days ("day") VALUES ('2022-12-06');

create table items (item varchar(20), price numeric(12,6), date_added date);

INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('toys',22.82,'2022-01-06');
INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('toys',28.99,'2022-03-06');
INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('shoes',32.56,'2022-06-06');
INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('shoes',62.74,'2022-04-06');
INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('shoes',35.16,'2022-10-06');
INSERT INTO items (item,price,date_added) VALUES ('toys',28.99,'2022-06-06');
```

Comment: I only have two tables one of dates and one of the items is this query assuming I have 3 tables?

Comment: It's assuming only 2 tables: days and items, I'll put the scripts I used to simulate

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account the min and max date for each item and join accordingly to the days list:

```
SELECT d.day, i.item, t.price
FROM (SELECT item, MIN(date_added) min_date, MAX(date_added) max_date FROM items GROUP BY item) i
INNER JOIN days d ON d.day BETWEEN i.min_date AND i.max_date
LEFT JOIN items t ON t.item = i.item AND t.date_added = d.day
ORDER BY i.min_date, i.item, d.day;
```

Note that, your dates as they are they are not comparable and you need to change their format to `YYYY-MM-DD` in all the tables.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=30d849b75a492e6a53315a4155f255b7).